# TypeError: Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined while using sequelize in node

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js, passport-local

I am getting belo mentioned error when trying to make user authentication using passport-local and sequelize for MySQL. When running server it is creating new table in SQL if not already, but as soon as I hit sign up button it is showing error.

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined
    at Strategy._verify (E:\Web Development\node-SQL-Sequelize-passport-local\config\passport\passport.js:19:13)
    at Strategy.authenticate (E:\Web Development\node-SQL-Sequelize-passport-local\node_modules\passport-local\lib\strategy.js:88:12)
    at attempt (E:\Web Development\node-SQL-Sequelize-passport-local\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:361:16)
    at authenticate (E:\Web Development\node-SQL-Sequelize-passport-local\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:362:7)
```

My **`server.js`** look like :

```
app.use(passport.initialize());

app.use(passport.session()); 




//Models
var models = require("./app/models");

//Routes
var authRoute = require('./app/routes/auth.js')(app,passport);
require('./config/passport/passport.js')(passport, models.user);

//Sync Database
models.sequelize.sync().then(function() {

    console.log('Nice! Database looks fine')

}).catch(function(err) {

    console.log(err, "Something went wrong with the Database Update!")

});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {

    res.send('Welcome to Passport with Sequelize');

});
```

My **`user.js`** file:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, Sequelize) {

    var User = sequelize.define('userInfo', {

        id: {
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER
        },

        firstname: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            notEmpty: true
        },

        lastname: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            notEmpty: true
        },

        username: {
            type: Sequelize.TEXT
        },

        about: {
            type: Sequelize.TEXT
        },

        email: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            validate: {
                isEmail: true
            }
        },

        password: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },

        last_login: {
            type: Sequelize.DATE
        },

        status: {
            type: Sequelize.ENUM('active', 'inactive'),
            defaultValue: 'active'
        }


    });

    return User;

}
```

My **`passport.js`** file :

```
var bCrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

module.exports = function(passport, user) {
    var User = user;
    var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
    passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy(

    {
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password',
        passReqToCallback: true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback

    },function(req, email, password, done) {
        var generateHash = function(password) {

        return bCrypt.hashSync(password, bCrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);

        };
        User.findOne({
        where: {
            email: email
        }
        }).then(function(user) {

            if (user)

            {

                return done(null, false, {
                    message: 'That email is already taken'
                });

            } else

            {

                var userPassword = generateHash(password);

                var data =

                    {
                        email: email,

                        password: userPassword,

                        firstname: req.body.firstname,

                        lastname: req.body.lastname

                    };


                    User.create(data).then(function(newUser, created) {

                    if (!newUser) {

                        return done(null, false);

                    }

                        if (newUser) {

                            return done(null, newUser);

                        }

                    });

            }

        });

    }

));

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Review this example: [github.com/sequelize/express-example](https://github.com/sequelize/express-example). In particular models/index.js for models load.

That way is handled in that example is:

```
require('./config/passport/passport.js')(passport, models.userInfo);
```

Because "userInfo" is defined in your model user.js: